# Safe to use <%# in non-data binding manner

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I came across some code where the original programmer is using `<%# ... %>` in the page where it does nothing related to data binding. It is being used to output a string to the page. Is this safe? Does `<%#` behave like `<%=` in this case or `<%:` ?

Comment: are you sure Page.DataBind is not called?

Comment: Right.  If DataBind is not called nothing will be output.

Comment: I have used a technique similar to what you describe when placing dynamic Link urls in a content place holder when using nested master pages. ASP.NET complains if you have dynamic code (`<%=`) in a place holder that contains a nested place holder. By replacing it with `<%# Page.ResolveUrl...` you can call Page.DataBind in the code behind to support both scenarios...not a great solution but it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does <%# behave like <%= in this case or <%: ?

Only if the code inside the tag explicitly calls Response.Write() or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The expression between <%# ... %> is evaluated and converted to a string. The result is assigned to  a property of a control or, if there is no control, a DataBoundLiteralControl is added. Is it safe? Yes. When the page is accessed for the first time, ASP .Net parses it, generates a new class and compiles it into an assembly, including the code in these blocks.

What is between <%= ... %>, acts the same as the previous, BUT the result is not assigned to any property, it is used by the HtmlTextWriter.Write method, which, btw, returns void so it won't work if you try to use it in a databinding expression.

**What about the :**

This can be used in the both constructs, : is a safety plus, because the evaluated string is html encoded via System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode.
So you can use it with the data bindings construct <%#: or with the writer construct <%: (without =).

**Tip**

Write something in the constructs which will give a compilation error, click on Show Complete Compilation Source, and navigate to that line. The black box is not a black box anymore.